# How to prevent conversion of number forms to numbers in Import [ webpage, "Data" ]?

Tags: import

I have tabular data on a webpage. It looks like this:

```
Import["http://mfvonh.me/numericalTable.html", "Plaintext"]
```

> 1.0
>
> 1.1
>
> 3.53

However, I have many columns, so I want to import it using `"Data"`:

```
Import[ "http://mfvonh.me/numericalTable.html" , "Data" ]
```

> { 1. , 1.1 , 3.53 }

I'd like to prevent `Import` from converting number-like forms to numbers, as it has done above, and simply extract all tabular data as strings. Obviously there are easy ways to hack this with a workaround; I am looking for an answer that involves `Import[ _ , "Data" ]`.

I assume this conversion is somewhere in the `Trace`, but I was overwhelmed when I tried to look at it:

```
(Import["http://mfvonh.me/numericalTable.html", "Data"] // 
  Trace) >> "trace.txt"
```

produced **26 megabytes** of plain text.

I took a look. Now I'm stuck.

Comment: I guess you can leave out the edit, as long as it duplicates your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `"Numeric" -> False` option:

```
Import["http://mfvonh.me/numericalTable.html", "Data", "Numeric" -> False]
```

> {"1.0", "1.1", "3.53"}

This option is listed under Options on [the Documentation page for HTML](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HTML.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
Block[
  {ToExpression},
  ToExpression[ x_String /; 
    StringMatchQ[ x, RegularExpression[ "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?" ] ] ] := x ;
  Import[ "http://mfvonh.me/numericalTable.html" , "Data" ] ]
```

> > {"1.0", "1.1", "3.53"}

Comment: +1 for resourcefulness, although in this case your solution is an overkill. :)